# Do you know of any good rectangular spice storage solutions?

Tags: spices, storage, organization

Currently I'm storing most of my spices in a cabinet next to the stove. That's the best place for them. However, because of the way the shelves are spaced, I generally need to stack containers, leading to a pretty huge mess in our spice cabinet.

I'd like to get some containers that are relatively uniform in size so they can be stacked on top of each other without falling all over the place. And I'd like them to be rectangular or some other non-circular shape so they can be placed in rows easily. And, for the tricky part, I'd like containers that have some sort of shaker part so I can shake the spices in if I want to. Any suggestions?

I've seen some very expensive things out there and am wondering whether there are other options. I can store spices that don't fit in the containers on the second shelf of the cabinet, so I don't mind the size  quite as much.

Comment: Why can't round stackable containers be placed in rows?

Comment: Have you ever heard of gladware? 5+lids for $2.50. I nave seen some as small as 3x3x2 in. More expensive ones have mechanism interlocking top to bottom. And you certainly could shake your spices in any of those.

Comment: @BlessedGeek 3x3x2" is 2-3 times as big as normal spice jars. And the wording in the post is a little funny, but the OP isn't asking to shake things *in* a a container. She wants shaker tops, to shake spices out of the jars in small quantities. I doubt you'll find those for food storage containers.

Comment: I am not sure if we should keep or close this question, as it is in the grey zone of the shopping question guidelines, http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/are-shopping-requests-on-topic-or-should-them-be-considered-too-localized. I think that the trend has been to close all shopping questions lately, but will let the community decide on this one.

Comment: I would vote to close, but I did so a long time ago; that vote has decayed and now I am not permitted to vote again.

Comment: I'm definitely OK with closing it, but don't think I have permissions to do so. I very much appreciate all of the suggested answers! Sorry I wasn't aware of the shopping question guidelines!

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this is to use the containers I already have and put them on this:

[image: double decker lazy susan]

It's called a double decker lazy susan. I've had mine about 30 years but I'm sure they are still sold. It spins to make it easy to access anything. You put some spices on the top shelf and some on the bottom.

Comment: I *love* that model ... unfortunately, all of the newer ones that I can find are much thicker shelves and more space between levels, so I can't get two sets of standard height spice bottles in my cabinet ... I can only fit those little short (< 2" / 5cm tall) ones on top.

Comment: you can probably get them on ebay. I found this image on etsy and it looks exactly like mine.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of [these](http://www.foodiekitchen.com/Shopitem.asp?SKU=SPICE_JAR_SET_RECTANGULAR)?
They are rectangular, and not ugly but perhaps a bit expensive.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about a magnetic spice rack?

This one is from the Container Store, but there are several different models out there:

http://www.containerstore.com/shop/kitchen/spiceStorage?productId=10011223

This way, you could hang an inexpensive magnetic strip inside the cupboard door (You can find them at most craft stores, IKEA, etc) and then attach your spices to it. I use this method, and I really like it.

You could also hot glue/super glue big magnets to your existing containers and put them on the strips that way.

Answer (score 2):

Emsa has [spice organizers](http://www.emsa.com/english/products/housewares/kitchen-world/spicing/spicing-page-1/) designed to solve this problem. I don't know if they are available worldwide, but at least in Europe, it shouldn't be too hard to get them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some places you can buy the spice in a stackable rectangular container.  Check out these types from [Clubhouse](http://www.clubhouse.ca/en/school_house/spice_storage_tips.aspx). They come with shaker, and larger opennings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have bought freeze-dried spices in small, square carton-like containers that are meant to be stored in the fridge (they don't have to be), and are easy to make a row of in the inside door of my fridge - dill, parsley, etc.  Storable for a long time, actually. These could be adapted to the counter.  They're sold under the "President's Choice" label, and perhaps others?

Also, "TableFare" has an interesting triangular, stackable system which doesn't take up a lot of space - don't know the price, sorry - www.tablefare.com

Answer (score 0):

I personally use two lazy susans, like Kate has mentioned ... but if also have the option of finding a 'spice rack', where you have a set of shelves or a carosel that holds the spices horizontal.  The carousel ones generally come with jars (sometimes with stale spices already in them), the shelves might not, but they're more flexible in dealing with non-uniform containers.

... but you can also get [shallow wire shelves](http://www.containerstore.com/shop/kitchen/spiceStorage?productId=10000897) that have a lip that you can mount to the inside of the cabinet door ... so that you pull the front row of spices to the door and reducing the number that you have to look behind on your shelves.  The multi-shelf ones require better measuring when you install, as you want to make sure that you don't have the rack or bottles in the same plane as the cabinet's shelf.